# Inject services on demand on Guard

Tags: nestjs

I have a guard that checks the ownership of a resource. If the user is the owner (created that resource), then he can access (update, read, delete).

Each resource is handled by its own service (comments is handled by the `CommentsModule` which has the `CommentsService` and so on). Each service that handles a resource with ownership implements a function called `hasOwnership` and the guard will call said function.

If possible, I would like my guard to inject the correct service depending on the controller that is calling it. So, if `CommentsController` is calling the guard, then it should inject and use `CommentsService.hasOwnership`.

I have tried using dynamic modules to inject the correct module/service on the `imports` of `ACModule` which hosts the guard, but that seems to be a no go as I can't properly handle the circular dependencies.

Injecting every service into the guard and selecting the correct will be very troublesome to mantain, due to the circular dependencies.

Is there a better way? This would be the desirable behavior.

```
@Injectable()
export default class ACGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    @Inject('SERVICE_KEY') private correctService
  ) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    return await correctService.hasOwnership();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need a different service at run time (instead of at compile time) you are going to need to take a factory approach. It is a little troublesome to maintain as new resources are added but that's the trade-off you have to make.

First thing I would do is create a factory class to determine which service is the correct service to use based on the ExecutionContext:

```
export interface IService {
  hasOwnership() : Promise<boolean>;
}

@Injectable()
export class ServiceFactory {

  //Make sure every service returned from this method implements the "IService" interface
  public getCorrectService(context: ExecutionContext) : IService {

    if(context...) {
      return new CommentsService();
    } else if(context...) {
      return new SomeOtherService();
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can inject that factory into your guard to get the correct service:

```
@Injectable()
export default class ACGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private serviceFactory: ServiceFactory) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {

    //Here's where the magic of this happens...
    const correctService: Iservice = this.serviceFactory.getCorrectService(context);

    return await correctService.hasOwnership();
  }
}
```

Comment: That was a really good explanation. Thank you! I actually read this a while ago, weighted the positives and negatives and decided to go with service specific guards. I am now marking it as correct so you get your beautiful points :D

Comment: @MarceloPerrella glad it worked out for you, happy to help :)